# Python statistics package mean() gives wrong answer from pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, statistics

I'm using Python 3.6, trying to get the mean of some values in a subset of a row of a pandas dataframe (pandas version 0.23.4).  I'm getting the values with .loc[] and then trying to get the mean of them with mean() from the python statistics package, like so:

```
import statistics as st
rows = ['row1','row2','row3']
somelist = []
for i in rows:
    a = df.loc[i,"Q1":"Q7"]
    somelist.append(st.mean(a))
```

I end up getting answers without any decimal places.  If I manually write in the answers to items Q1:Q7 into a list, this is the result:

```
a = st.mean([2,3,4,4,2,6,5])
print(a)
Out: 3.7142857142857144
```

But if that sequence was what I pulled from the dataframe, I get a mean with no decimal places, like so:

```
a = st.mean(df.loc[i,"Q1":"Q7"])
Out: 3
```

Evidently it's because it thinks it's a numpy.int64 instead of a float.  This happens even if I convert the slice from the dataframe into a list, like this:

```
a = st.mean(list(df.loc[i,"Q1":"Q7"]))
Out: 3
```

Weirdly, it does NOT happen if I use .mean() :

```
a = df.loc[i,"Q1":"Q7"].mean()
Out: 3.7142857142857144
```

I double-checked the st.stdev() method and it seems to work fine.  What's going on?  Why does it want to print out an integer for the mean automatically? Thanks!

Comment: Another simple example: `st.mean([np.int64(1), np.int64(2)])` returns 1, not 1.5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`statistics.mean` converts the output to the same type as the inputs.  If the input values are all, say, `numpy.int64`, the result is converted to `numpy.int64`.  Here's the source for `statistics.mean` in Python 3.6.7:

```
def mean(data):
    """Return the sample arithmetic mean of data.

    >>> mean([1, 2, 3, 4, 4])
    2.8

    >>> from fractions import Fraction as F
    >>> mean([F(3, 7), F(1, 21), F(5, 3), F(1, 3)])
    Fraction(13, 21)

    >>> from decimal import Decimal as D
    >>> mean([D("0.5"), D("0.75"), D("0.625"), D("0.375")])
    Decimal('0.5625')

    If ``data`` is empty, StatisticsError will be raised.
    """
    if iter(data) is data:
        data = list(data)
    n = len(data)
    if n < 1:
        raise StatisticsError('mean requires at least one data point')
    T, total, count = _sum(data)
    assert count == n
    return _convert(total/n, T)
```

Note that `total/n` is converted to the input type before being returned.

To avoid this, you could convert the input to floating point before passing it to `statistics.mean`.

Comment: Great, thank you - I made them into floats and it worked!

Answer (score 0):

I think you are doing the things in the for part wrong. Try printing the a for each row that you are going trough and the appended mean in the list.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  It actually still happens outside of the for loop, though!

Comment: What values do you get when you print somelist after the loop is done, because I can see that you have 3 rows but you are putting 7 elemets to do the mean after that.

Comment: the elements are from the column titled Q1 to the column titled Q7 (so for the toy example I did up there, there'd be 3 rows but I'm looking for the mean of each row over 7 columns)